# Migrating plsql function to pgplsql (postgresql 9.5)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate the next function into PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mar.change_const (command text) RETURNS 
VOID AS $body$
DECLARE

C_Procedure_Name   CONSTANT   varchar(30) := 'change_constraints';
V_Step                        real := 0;
/* command values: ENABLE | DISABLE */
all_constraints CURSOR(stat text) FOR
       SELECT *
       FROM   all_constraints
       WHERE  status = stat;
cons                          all_constraints%ROWTYPE;
line                          varchar(200);
cons_status                   varchar(10);
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'Start : %, %', C_Procedure_Name, TO_CHAR(clock_timestamp());
V_Step := 1;
IF command IN ('enable', 'ENABLE') THEN
  cons_status := 'DISABLED';
ELSE
  cons_status := 'ENABLED';
END IF;
V_Step := 2;
FOR cons IN all_constraints(cons_status)
LOOP
    V_Step := 2.1;
    line := 'alter table ' || cons.table_name || ' ' || command ||
            ' novalidate constraint ' || CONS.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
    V_Step := 2.2;
    EXECUTE line;
END LOOP;
```

I know that I can switch all_constraints with `information_schema.table_constraints` but how can I change the other parts of the code ? I can't disable and enable constraints in PostgreSQL and I don't want to drop them in this part.

I read that I can alter the check constraints (which are the only type of constraint that I have) to `novalidate` but I didn't find any example in a search engine.

Comment: Use the format() function. That will at least solve the quoting problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `NO VALID` mark for check constraint only on `ADD CONSTRAINT`, so you can't do it without dropping old `CHECK CONSTRAINT` first. Accordingly "ENABLE" here would be `ALTER TABLE ...VALIDATE` which would lock the table and go over all data (re)validating it.

FK constraints are the only type you can "comfortably" "disable/enable" by `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER ALL` and then enabling them back.

But in short the procedure above is so much different from Postgres way of dealing with constraints, that I doubt you will success much here. Probably you have to save definition of all existing constraints, drop them and recreate from saved definitions to "enable"...

Comment: Is there any postgresql function that get as parameter an object (constraint for example) and gives you back the create command that was used for it ?

Comment: for any type - no. constraints can be partially DDL'ed with ```select pg_get_constraintdef(oid) from pg_constraint where conname = 'b_i_fkey';```